# How to generate random IDs for client database using MongoDB/Node.js/Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hey guys I am currently working on an app that stores client information. Everything works well up until I get to client Ids. I'm not sure what the best method is...

I'm currently using Mongodb/mongoose/node.js.

I thought about creating a model for usedNums and just pushing each id into an array of numbers within one instance of that model. I could then compare every new randomly generated id to the "usedNums" but I'm not sure if it's a good idea to create a model for that specific use.

I also thought about generating a random ID and using:

```
Client.find({"id" : "randomID"}, function(err, matchedID)...
```

But I am not sure if "matchedID" is returned as undefined if nothing is matched in the DB. If it is, I could just..

```
If(matchedID === undefined){
    client.clientId = randomID;
    client.save();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean you want to create a random ID? You don't want to use the _id property that comes with mongo?

Comment: I certainly could, I just figured client ids would start from 1 and go up.

Comment: How about https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: The main issue with ObjectId is that the number is looooong.

Answer (score -1):

Use auto incrementing sequence:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/